# Save entire file from GREP results

Tags: awk, grep, cygwin, gnuwin32

Okay so I'm using grep on a external HDD

example,

```
M:/

grep -rhI "bananas" . > out.txt
```

which would output any lines within " M:/ " containing " bananas "

However I would like to output the entire contents of the file, so if one line in example.txt contains " bananas " output entire content of example.txt and same goes for any other .txt file within directory " M:/ " that contains " bananas ".

Comment: Have you thought to use the '-l' option for grep to output filenames and you pipe this command with 'xargs cat' ? It will output the content of all your files. At least, it works on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

To print the contents of any file name containing the string `bananas` would be:

```
find . -type f -exec grep 'bananas' -l --null {} + | xargs -0 cat
```

The above uses GNU tools to handle with file names containing newlines.

Forget you ever saw any grep args to recursively find files, adding those args to GNU grep was a terrible idea and just makes your code more complicated. Use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to **g/re/p** within files.

Comment: I'm curious: why quote the `{}`?  For consistency, it seems this ought to be `xargs "-0" "cat" "{}"`

Comment: But I think you just want `xargs -0 cat` in any case.

Comment: The quotes are just being over-cautious since I don;t use that command much so don't know for SURE how it behaves when the file name contains globbing chars and white space. You're right though I dont need the `{} at all so removing it now, thx.